# Baking chicken while respecting maximum olive oil temperature

Tags: baking, food-safety, olive-oil

I normally cook chicken on a pan with some olive oil (which supports a maximum temperature of 160C) but I am trying to bake on the oven instead.

I've found a recipe where some olive oil placed at the bottom of tray together with some balsamic vinegar and some spices but the recipe indicates to set the oven temperature to 200C.

Knowing that the maximum temperature for the olive oil is the 160C I set the oven temperature to that and increase the cooking time for the chicken (instead of 20 minutes I used 1 hour). On the last 5 minutes or so, I increased to 190C.

The chicken looks cooked inside but I am concerned now if whether or not it had reached a safe temperature after reading [Can I safely roast a chicken for 4 to 5 hours on a low heat?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/6032/can-i-safely-roast-a-chicken-for-4-to-5-hours-on-a-low-heat) .

1. If I set the oven temperature to 200C, will it cause degradation on the portion of olive oil, considering its maximum recommended temperature of 160C? Likely the oil will not reach the 200C but what temperature should I use?
2. How safe should it be to eat this chicken now? Should I apply some extra cooking to be sure?

thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure what your concern is. I use olive oil fro 90% of my cooking applications.  It is often in higher oven temps than 200C...and the best way to determine chicken done-ness is to measure the internal temperature.

Comment: Where did you get that olive oil cannot handle more than 160C?

Comment: @GdD: That information is everywhere. For example on https://oliveoilsource.com/page/heating-olive-oil it is explained that cooking should not exceed the 'smoke point'. It seems for extra virgin oil (the ones common used for salads, more tasty) the maximum temperature is around 185C) while for non virgin oil is higher, around 210C. On the bottle of mine, it's mentioned max of 160C, I realize now I had bought the extra virgin one (1 liter!) where I wanted to buy a proper one for cooking :( The previous brand I got I read now it can take up to 210C...

Comment: Ok, that answers my #1 question (I should have used non virgin oil). Now for #2, would it be safe to eat the chicken I cooked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got my answer. Thanks to GdD to put me into the right track. I was using an olive oil not suitable for cooking. I got now one now capable of handling up to 210C. I think I need to do a lot of salads to make use of the previous 1 liter olive oil bottle though :P

BTW, i tried the chicken, not problems so far by eating it. Likely was still enough well cooked.